# Cannon JS — Position Vector NaN after initiating body with properties

Tags: javascript, three.js, physics, cannon.js

I'm using a simple setup Cannon.js, following the examples online, but when I set any property in the constructor, the position and angular velocity x, y and z are all NaN.

This works, but does not move, as the body has no mass.

```
const body = new CANNON.Body();
console.log(body.position.x, body.mass); //logs 0, 0
```

However, this doesn't...

```
const body = new CANNON.Body({
    mass: 1,
});
console.log(body.position.x, body.mass); //logs NaN, 1
```

Also if I instantiate the body, and then set the mass after, it still doesn't move.

Some more code for context (I am calling the update function in an animation loop, and it's happening A-OK).

```
export const init = () => {
world = new CANNON.World();
world.gravity.set(0,1,0);
world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase();
world.solver.iterations = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < BODIES_COUNT; i++) {
    const shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(4,4,4));
    const body = new CANNON.Body({
        mass: 1,
    });
    const body = new CANNON.Body();
    body.addShape(shape);
    body.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    body.mass = 1;
    body.angularVelocity.set(0, 2, 0);
    body.velocity.set(0, 1, 0);
    body.angularDamping = 0.5;

    world.addBody(body);
    bodies.push(body);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    meshes.push(mesh);
}
}

export const update = (delta) => {
    world.step(TIMESTEP * delta);
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the body.position.x === NaN problem using Cannon.js v0.6.2 on NPM, not via the master branch version either. Also, running your code above should throw a syntax error since you define "const body" twice.

Comment: The second body is a mistake — It's not actually in my code, somehow it creeped in here while I was writing the question. Removing it now.
I'm using v0.6.2 also — very odd why this is not working. I can only think it could be some error with Babelify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you accidentally pass `delta = 0` to `world.step`. Repro using Cannon.js v0.6.2: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouexuwjd/)

Try changing your code to:

```
export const update = (delta) => {
    if (delta > 0) {
        world.step(TIMESTEP * delta);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, yes I think that was the issue. On the first loop the delta is 0, I didn't expect this to be a problem, but seems like it was. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. This is actually a bug in Cannon - step() should be able to handle a zero argument. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Aha — I thought it seemed like odd behavior. Glad to be of help. Great library by the way, nice work. If you have any good learning resources then please send them my way. Have found some but maybe you know of some good ones.